# Simple Regex to replace all with same amount

Tags: php, regex, replace

I cant seem to get this right !

I'm trying to replace same amount of spaces with the same amount of other characters:

```
$s="abc  def f";
echo preg_replace('/[\s*]+/', 'X', $s);
```

### Expecting abcXXdefXf

Comment: You can simply use `str_replace(" ", "X", $s);` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need regexp for this?

```
$s = 'abc  def f';
echo str_replace(' ', 'X', $s); // output: abcXXdefXf
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$s="abc  def f";
echo preg_replace('/\s/', 'X', $s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `str_replace`.

```
str_replace(" ", "X", $s);
```